# How to chech the final listbox when drag drop listbox item

Tags: excel, vba, listbox-control

whit excel vba I has created one form to assign the services at each operator. 
My goal will be: select a service from TotalServices ListBox, drag it into a UserListbox (A,B,C,D..)
But I can't define(find) the destination listbox(like A,B,C,D,..), there are a way to do this?!? 
here [dragDrop reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/beforedroporpaste-event) I saw that the parameter for Effect `Moves/Copy the drop source to the drop target`, right how I can retreive the target control.name?!??!

[image: Actual userform]

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. Your question is not clear. Could you upload your work: code, screenshots...

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego I just need to know if is possible to retreive/define the destination object.name when one user drag one listbox.item to the destination object. My image are one example where I've one (the biggest) listbox and 7 listboxs(A,B,C,D,..)  I need to know where (which listbox) I leave the listbox.item dragged from the primary listbox

Comment: this tread help me [a]https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/446895-need-help-code-drag-drop-post2209008.html#post2209008[/a]
thank